# Only some CSS custom properties work, although all are clearly present in the HTML and shown by the inspector

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I'm working on implementing different themes across my website. I've refactored my main stylesheet to feature variables, and have three other "theme" stylesheets that define those variables at the `:root` level. The final HTML then links to two stylesheets: The main stylesheet and one of the three theme stylesheets, which are switched on button click by changing the link's href attribute. Somehow, only some of the variables are working.

```css
/* dark.css (theme stylesheet only containing the custom properties) */
/* Only --background works */
:root {
    --background: #000000;

    --seperator: rgba(1,1,1,0.12);
    --text: #FFFFFF;

    --block-border: #404040;
    --block-shadow: #000000;
    --block-background: #151017;
}

/* All properties work except for --comment */
code {
    --keyword: #F72057;
    --type: #FF9519;
    --call: #FF5700;
    --property: #FF5700;
    --number: #F72057;
    --string: #F72057;
    --comment: #FFFFFF;
    --dot-access: #FF5700;
    --preprocessing: #646485;
}
```

When I then go into the inspector, everything seems to be alright. I can see the proper inheritance, and I can even click on the variable where it's used and see the intended color.

Some examples of how the variables are used:

```css
/* styles.css (main stylesheet) */
body {
    ...
    background: var(--background);
    color: var(--text);
}

pre code .comment {
    color: ￼var(--comment);
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

---

#### Other approaches

I've tried several other approaches, all of which led to the same result (only some variables working).

1. Instead of linking to another stylesheet, directly change the variables with javascript on the HTML tag
2. Instead of linking to multiple stylesheets, having three separate main stylesheets
3. Changing a custom attribute in the HTML tag and defining all variables like `[theme="dark"] {...}` in one main stylesheet

Comment: What's `￼` in front of comment

Comment: you have strange character added in your code, I guess it's the issue

Answer (score 1):

As `@Pushkin` and `@Temany Afif` have pointed out, there were strange characters all over my code. A quick project-wide find and replace solved the problem.